# Need GridLayoutManager with reversed layout manager with scrolls on top and item arrangement fully reversed

Tags: android, android-layout, android-recyclerview, firebaseui

Anybody knows how to reverse layout in `GridLayoutManager` and arrange items like in Instagram. As you know `setStackFromEnd` doesn't work, and `setReverseLayout` reverses list but not properly and scrollbar goes down automatically. I want to have reversed layout with scroll bars up.

Answer (score 1):

To keep your *Scrollbars up* scroll to Top (in reverse arrangement).

```
recyclerView.smoothScrollToPosition(0);
```

**OR instead** of `reversing GridLayoutManager` you can try the below code to keep the scrollBars up:

```
List<Object> reverseList = Lists.reverse(yourList);
```

pass it to the adapter:

```
YourAdapter adapter = new YourAdapter(reverseList);
```

Comment: Do you know how it can be done with firebaseRecyclerAdapter?

Comment: `mLayoutManager.setReverseLayout(true); mLayoutManager.setStackFromEnd(true);` did you try this ?

Comment: setStackFromEnd() is not valid for gridLayoutManager.

Comment: `smoothScrollToPosition` not working ? @VikashSharma

Answer (score 0):

Use the below code.

```
Collections.reverse(yourList); // add your ArrayList in "yourList"
```

Don't do anything with GridLayoutManager because GridLayoutManager does not support stackFromEnd(true).

I hope it is helpful.